# error building app with hermes: '..' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: react-native, react-native-hermes

- **Building the react-native app on Windows 10.**
- **The error is printed for line 165 of** `node_modules\react-native\react.gradle`:

*'..' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file*

**Line 165 is the 5th line in the following, starting with `exec`:**

```
if (enableHermes) {
                doLast {
                    def hermesFlags;
                    def hbcTempFile = file("${jsBundleFile}.hbc")
                    exec {
                        if (targetName.toLowerCase().contains("release")) {
                            // Can't use ?: since that will also substitute valid empty lists
                            hermesFlags = config.hermesFlagsRelease
                            if (hermesFlags == null) hermesFlags = ["-O", "-output-source-map"]
                        } else {
                            hermesFlags = config.hermesFlagsDebug
                            if (hermesFlags == null) hermesFlags = []
                        }

                        if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
                            commandLine("cmd", "/c", getHermesCommand(), "-emit-binary", "-out", hbcTempFile, jsBundleFile, *hermesFlags)
                        } else {
                            commandLine(getHermesCommand(), "-emit-binary", "-out", hbcTempFile, jsBundleFile, *hermesFlags)
                        }
                    }
                    ant.move(
                        file: hbcTempFile,
                        toFile: jsBundleFile
                    );
                    if (hermesFlags.contains("-output-source-map")) {
                        ant.move(
                            // Hermes will generate a source map with this exact name
                            file: "${jsBundleFile}.hbc.map",
                            tofile: jsCompilerSourceMapFile
                        );
                        exec {
                            // TODO: set task dependencies for caching

                            // Set up the call to the compose-source-maps script
                            workingDir(reactRoot)
                            if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
                                commandLine("cmd", "/c", *nodeExecutableAndArgs, composeSourceMapsPath, jsPackagerSourceMapFile, jsCompilerSourceMapFile, "-o", jsOutputSourceMapFile)
                            } else {
                                commandLine(*nodeExecutableAndArgs, composeSourceMapsPath, jsPackagerSourceMapFile, jsCompilerSourceMapFile, "-o", jsOutputSourceMapFile)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

**Here is the definition of hermescommand in android/app/build.gradle:**

```
project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: true,  // clean and rebuild if changing
    // next added by Yossi
    hermesCommand: "../../node_modules/hermesengine/win64-bin/hermes",
    extraPackagerArgs: ["--sourcemap-output", "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release/index.android.bundle.map"]
]
```

**Which, as far as I understand, points to the following file:**

```
node_modules\hermes-engine\win64-bin\hermes.exe
```

Any idea?

**Updated definition in android/app/build.gradle (following the answer below):**

```
project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: true,  // clean and rebuild if changing
    // -either- hermesCommand: "..\\..\\node_modules\\hermesengine\\win64-bin\\hermes",
    // -or- hermesCommand: "../../node_modules/hermesengine/%OS-BIN%/hermes",
    hermesCommand: "../../node_modules/hermesengine/%OS-BIN%/hermes",
    extraPackagerArgs: ["--sourcemap-output", "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release/index.android.bundle.map"]
]
```

#### The build output now, after the change, is the following:

```
> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
warning: the transform cache was reset.
                 Welcome to React Native!
                Learn once, write anywhere


info Writing bundle output to:, C:\esites-grocery\test1\plumpclient\android\app\build\generated\assets\react\release\index.android.bundle
info Writing sourcemap output to:, C:\esites-grocery\test1\plumpclient\android\app\build/intermediates/assets/release/index.android.bundle.map
info Done writing bundle output
info Done writing sourcemap output
info Copying 141 asset files
info Done copying assets
The system cannot find the path specified.

> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED

> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets_SentryUpload_3001
Processing react-native sourcemaps for Sentry upload.
> Analyzing 2 sources
> Rewriting sources
> Adding source map references
Uploading sourcemaps for release com.plumpplum@RN62 Hermes+3001 distribution 3001
> Bundled 2 files for upload
> Uploaded release files to Sentry
> File upload complete

Source Map Upload Report
  Minified Scripts
    ~/index.android.bundle (sourcemap at index.android.bundle.map)
  Source Maps
    ~/index.android.bundle.map

> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets_SentryUpload_1001
Processing react-native sourcemaps for Sentry upload.
> Analyzing 2 sources
> Rewriting sources
> Adding source map references
Uploading sourcemaps for release com.plumpplum@RN62 Hermes+1001 distribution 1001
> Bundled 2 files for upload
> Uploaded release files to Sentry
> File upload complete

Source Map Upload Report
  Minified Scripts
    ~/index.android.bundle (sourcemap at index.android.bundle.map)
  Source Maps
    ~/index.android.bundle.map

> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets_SentryUpload_2001
Processing react-native sourcemaps for Sentry upload.
> Analyzing 2 sources
> Rewriting sources
> Adding source map references
Uploading sourcemaps for release com.plumpplum@RN62 Hermes+2001 distribution 2001
> Bundled 2 files for upload
> Uploaded release files to Sentry
> File upload complete

Source Map Upload Report
  Minified Scripts
    ~/index.android.bundle (sourcemap at index.android.bundle.map)
  Source Maps
    ~/index.android.bundle.map

> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets_SentryUpload_4001
Processing react-native sourcemaps for Sentry upload.
> Analyzing 2 sources
> Rewriting sources
> Adding source map references
Uploading sourcemaps for release com.plumpplum@RN62 Hermes+4001 distribution 4001
> Bundled 2 files for upload
> Uploaded release files to Sentry
> File upload complete

Source Map Upload Report
  Minified Scripts
    ~/index.android.bundle (sourcemap at index.android.bundle.map)
  Source Maps
    ~/index.android.bundle.map

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\esites-grocery\test1\plumpclient\node_modules\react-native\react.gradle' line: 165

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
> Process 'command 'cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Comment: Are you saying that the output of `getHermesCommand()` only contains two dots?

Comment: I see what you see.... Seems so.

Comment: Why? Did you set `project.ext.react.hermesCommand` and accidentally add a space after two dots?

Comment: Please see at the bottom of my question (updated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's more of `react.gradle`:

```
def getHermesCommand = {
    // If the project specifies a Hermes command, don't second guess it.
    if (!hermesCommand.contains("%OS-BIN%")) {
        return hermesCommand
    }

    // Execution on Windows fails with / as separator
    return hermesCommand
            .replaceAll("%OS-BIN%", getHermesOSBin())
            .replace('/' as char, File.separatorChar);
}
```

You are specifying `../../node_modules/hermesengine/win64-bin/hermes` as the path, which is OS specific (as determined by not having an OS placeholder).

As per the comment, `react.gradle` therefore doesn't second guess your path and just passes it directly to the OS command interpreter.

This fails because your command interpreter does not allow `/` as directory separator.

Either specify a path that's valid for your system:

```
hermesCommand: "..\\..\\node_modules\\hermesengine\\win64-bin\\hermes",
```

Or specify an OS-independent path to let `react.gradle` transform it for each platform:

```
hermesCommand: "../../node_modules/hermesengine/%OS-BIN%/hermes",
```

Comment: I am getting for both "The system cannot find the path specified."

Comment: Does it still say `'..'` for both?

Comment: Do you mean the definition of the path? I updated it according to your suggestion. See updated at the bottom of my question.

Comment: No, I mean what is the complete error message with all information before, after and around it. Is the path it complains about still just two dots in both cases?

Comment: Sorry... Attached to my question.

Comment: Can you check the path and make sure there actually is such a file there? Are you overriding it on purpose, instead of leaving it as its default? Normally you wouldn't set it manually, and then it would use standard upstream `hermes-engine` instead of `hermesengine` and `hermesc` instead of `hermes`

Comment: I see now that I missed a dash in the path name (should be hermes-engine). And as you say, it is not needed at all, not sure any more why I added it in the first place. Anyway, the problem is gone now. getting another error, but it is getting late here... I will update tomorrow. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The other problem is in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64459496/react-native-hermes-warning-the-variable-promise-was-not-declared-in-functio, in case you have time...