# React-native/hermes build error. no such file or directory: index.android.bundle.packager.map

Tags: react-native, react-native-hermes

### Description

Getting the following messages during build with hermesEnabled set to true

*('...' represent removed text):*

(full error log is [here](https://filebin.net/2doudp9nqenhz72b/hermes-build-log.zip?t=5df00nbd))

```
android\app\build\generated\assets\react\release\index.android.bundle:13:134: warning: the variable "Promise" was not declared in function "isBoldTextEnabled"
...
android\app\build\generated\assets\react\release\index.android.bundle:27:2907: warning: the variable "DebuggerInternal" was not declared in function "value 14#"
...
android\app\build\generated\assets\react\release\index.android.bundle:92:57773: warning: the variable "setTimeout" was not declared in function "wi"
...

fs.js:114
    throw err;
    ^
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'android\app\build\intermediates\sourcemaps\react\release\index.android.bundle.packager.map'
at Object.openSync (fs.js:443:3)
at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:343:35)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\esites-grocery\test2.hermes\plumpclient\node_modules\react-native\scripts\compose-source-maps.js:33:43)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'node_modules\react-native\react.gradle' line: 191

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
> Process 'command 'cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

(The referenced file exists, at least after the build failed).

### Environment

- Building on Windows 10
- React Native version: 0.62.2

### What I tried to do

- Tried to bump soLoader to 0.8.0 and to 0.8.2 (although this is not supposed to be needed in RN 0.62.2) as suggested in https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25927#issuecomment-539415154

Comment: You're using the gradle wrapper and not gradle directly, right?

Comment: Right..........

Comment: The warnings should not matter. Is the `...` actually in the log?

Comment: No, I removed long text and placed ... instead.

Comment: The full log is very long. I uploaded it here, if you like to see it: https://filebin.net/2doudp9nqenhz72b/hermes-build-log.zip?t=5df00nbd

Comment: You're saying `C:\esites-grocery\test2.hermes\plumpclient\android\app\build\intermediates\sourcemaps\react\release\index.android.bundle.packager.map` exists with that exact name? Can you verify that `node` resolves to a Windows `node.exe` and not e.g. a WSL `node` binary?

Comment: You are right. again The file that exists there is index.android.bundle.compiler.map, not this one.

Comment: Any ideas why [this command](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/5333ad8a61b08cf0b25c72c328b997f3e3a4c2f3/react.gradle#L170-L172) does not end up creating the file? What does it run, and what happens when you run that yourself?

Comment: No idea... Shouldn't it be in the log? Searched for ' --bundle-output' and couldn't find it. How can I run it myself?

Comment: It should be, but I don't see it. I wouldn't know how to diagnose this without actually debugging the code, so I would have modified it to print out the parameters and tried that

Comment: I just modified the extra packages definition in build.gradle from extraPackagerArgs: ["--sourcemap-output", "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release/index.android.bundle.map"] to extraPackagerArgs: ["--sourcemap-output", "$buildDir/intermediates/sourcemaps/react/release/index.android.bundle.packager.map"] and there are no errors in the build (just the same warnings). An APK is created and it is running...

Answer (score 4):

Modifying the following extra packages definition in build.gradle:

```
extraPackagerArgs: ["--sourcemap-output", "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release/index.android.bundle.map"]
```

to

```
extraPackagerArgs: ["--sourcemap-output", "$buildDir/intermediates/sourcemaps/react/release/index.android.bundle.packager.map"]
```

Fixed the error (the warnings are still there).
An APK is created and is running..

Comment: Awesome, thanks for sharing your solution!

Answer (score 0):

`./gradlew clean`

After doing the ./gradlew clean It worked for me.

OR

For Windows:

`gralde clean`